# special character in jsonParsing

Tags: android

how to parse the special character in json parsing

content is incoded in utf-8.while decoding  sautéed and dispalying it I am getting saut?ed
My code is the following:

```
inputStream = (InputStream) new URL(url).getContent();
              return  convertStreamToString(inputStream);

  //converting into string
public static String convertStreamToString(InputStream is) throws IOException {
        String serverResponse=null;
        try{
//String serverResponse;
        if (is != null) {
            Writer writer = new StringWriter();

            char[] buffer = new char[1024];
            try {
                Reader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is,"UTF-8"));
                int n;
                while ((n = reader.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                    writer.write(buffer, 0, n);
                }
            } finally {
                is.close();
            }
            serverResponse= writer.toString();

            Log.e("response from server", serverResponse);
        } else {
            serverResponse= "{\"Error\":\"No response\"}";
        }
        return serverResponse;
        }catch(IOException e){
//          timeOut=true;
            serverResponse= "{\"Error\":\""+e.toString()+"\"}";
            Log.e("Red spcie utils converting to string failed",e.toString()    );
        }
        return serverResponse;
    }
```

I am getting ? mark in content for example -- man?o(mango)

Comment: You're claiming that the data is in UTF-8... are you sure that's correct?

Comment: @chandan: How do you know? Have you looked at the binary data that's coming over the wire? Could you give an example of the bytes in "sautéed"?

Comment: I am not sure about utf-8 but remaining character are getting displyed except special character  é

Comment: @chandan: That's what I'd expect if it were some encoding like 8859-1. You shouldn't just guess at an encoding. Find out what it really is.

Comment: Thanks Jon Skeet. I got the solution by using decoder as ISO8859_1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you Jon Skeet you are right .I got the solution by using the decoder as ISO8859_1
in

public static String convertStreamToString(InputStream is) throws IOException {
        String serverResponse=null;
        try{
//String serverResponse;
        if (is != null) {
            Writer writer = new StringWriter();

```
        char[] buffer = new char[1024];
        try {
            Reader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is,"ISO8859_1"));
            int n;
            while ((n = reader.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                writer.write(buffer, 0, n);
            }
        } finally {
            is.close();
        }
        serverResponse= writer.toString();

        Log.e("response from server", serverResponse);
    } else {
        serverResponse= "{\"Error\":\"No response\"}";
    }
    return serverResponse;
    }catch(IOException e){
```

//          timeOut=true;
            serverResponse= "{\"Error\":\""+e.toString()+"\"}";
            Log.e("Red spcie utils converting to string failed",e.toString()    );
        }
        return serverResponse;
    }